# How to create dictionary mapping keys to class methods and initialize this object in the same time

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

I'm creating a parser and what I want to do is a method which initializes object of class specified in dictionary and then call method on that class. Objects should be created at run-time, other every time this method is called. It's quite complicated, I think some pseudocode will explain it better:

```
# some_method places intialized object in some list    

dictionary_map = { 'foo': Bar.some_method, 'foo2': Bar2.some_method }

def parse_lines(lines):
    for line in lines:
        for key in dictionary_map: 
            if line.startswith(key):  # checking if line matches dict value
                dictionary_map[key](line)
```

I know I can pass 'self' argument like this:

```
f = Bar()
dictionary_map['foo'](f)
```

But that's not what I want to do. Dictionary is quite big and has many classes in it. I've tried something like this:

```
dictionary_map = { 'foo': Bar.some_method(object.__new__(Bar)) }
```

But just from looking at it I already know it's not how it should be :)

Comment: Do you just want `{'foo': lambda: Bar().some_method()}`?

Comment: maybe, what is `x` here? I don't know much about lambdas.

Comment: I have removed the `x` as, re-reading your question, you don't want to pass any arguments. That being said, if you are creating a class with no arguments then calling an instance method with no arguments, are you sure you need the class at all?

Comment: Oh, I wanna pass argument (`line`), forgot it in pseudocode. Yes, I need classes, they are used to store data in lists :) Thanks :)

Comment: Beware of keys that mask others - if you have a line that starts with "foo2" and you happen to test "foo" first, you will think there is a match. A simple approach to fix this is to test your dictionary keys in reverse order by length, so you will check longer keys before shorter ones.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire it's just example, but thanks for possible solution, maybe it will be useful in the future ^^

Comment: @Endy - your approach of passing the parsed tokens to the command-specific class is very similar to how I do this in pyparsing. The difference is that you are not currently doing anything with the created instances - in my case the instances get collected into a list which can then be called with some class method like `execute()` or `evaluate()`.  Here is a link to an adventure game I presented at PyCon'06 that directly mirrors your design, but using pyparsing: http://www.ptmcg.com/geo/python/confs/adventureEngine.py.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way (if I understand you correctly) would be to use a tuple containing the class and method separately:

```
dictionary_map = {'foo': (Bar, 'some_method'), 'foo2': (Bar2, 'some_method')}
```

Then you could create a new instance of the class and call its method like so:

```
cls, method = dictionary_map[key]
getattr(cls(), method)()
```

This means you can do more with the instance if needed.

Comment: *"you can do more with the instance if needed"* - not true, as it stands; you assign the *class* but not the *instance*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, you're right. I was just thinking of the general approach. You'd definitely need to assign `cls()` to use it again.